# pryr : calling object_size using cat

Tags: r

In package pryr (http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html) function object_size returns the size of an object.  For example object_size(1:1E8)  returns 400 MB.  It returns the value using appropriate units (B, KB, MB, GB, etc).  However, when called using cat, it returns the value in bytes only.  cat(object_size(1:1E8)) returns 4e+08.  How can I make it return using the original format (B, KB, MB...) when called using cat?  Usually I am displaying information on dataframes that I have created/imported using cat("mydb", dim(mydb), "\n").  I would like to add object_size to that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
cat(capture.output(object_size(1:1e8)))
```

This goes around the fact that `cat` does not apply the formatting that `print` does to its argument.

Answer (score 0):

`object_size` returns an object of class 'bytes'. I would have expected that you might succeed with the use of print(), but no. Unlike most print-methods `pryr:::print.bytes` does not actually return its argument, but rather works via the side-effect of using cat() to output a string to the console, and returns NULL-object. I'm not sure why that choice was made, but you could redefine `print.bytes`

```
pryr:::print.bytes   # to get the code
print.bytes <- 
function (x, digits = 3, ...) 
{
    power <- min(floor(log(abs(x), 1000)), 4)
    if (power < 1) {
        unit <- "B"
    }
    else {
        unit <- c("kB", "MB", "GB", "TB")[[power]]
        x <- x/(1000^power)
    }
    formatted <- format(signif(x, digits = digits), big.mark = ",", 
        scientific = FALSE)
    paste0(formatted, " ", unit, "\n", sep = "") # return character-object
}
```

Then you could assign the results of `print(object_size(x))`. You might want to leave off the "\n", though.